# Is there a way to use something like MappingManager on datastax java client 4.x

Tags: cassandra, datastax

In datastax 3.x there used to be mappingManager. We used it to get different mappers using `com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager#getMapper`.

I see that under the hood it uses `com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser#parseEntity`.

We want to upgrade our client to datastax 4.x, I see that the [mapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/mapper/) concept was changed and there is now a generated Mapper per Entity.

I have a large code base and I want to upgrade it step by step. Moreover, currently, I have some wrapper to the MappingManager and I want to use the same concept as possible at first stage.

However, I can't find how to have something similar to the mapping manager, just that every place in the code needs to know it on Entity when it needs to use it.

Is there a clean way to have something like `getMapper` on datastax 4.x? (Later I will clean this if needed, but I want to have this in the first place).

Comment: There is no exact equivalent I'm afraid. You need to somehow come up with a class annotated with @Mapper. But contrary to driver 3.x where everything is generated at runtime with reflection, for driver 4.x the exact entities you wish to map need to be all known and accessible at compile time.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. Thanks @adutra